# Does content uri trigger in firebase job dispatcher have a minSdk requirement

Tags: android, performance, firebase-job-dispatcher

I am trying to schedule a job when users change(add/delete/update) contacts using FirebaseJobDispatcher. Looking at the github repository https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/blob/3d82e89d1eb89cc7d0634cc0d71f96c45f63ce3d/jobdispatcher/src/test/java/com/firebase/jobdispatcher/ContentUriTriggerTest.java
it looks like its only been tested for SDK 21 and above. 
Is that the minSdk for this to work, because my app has a minSdk of 19?